# How to set label size in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, label, size

I would like to set label size the same as screen size.

f.e. for large screen large label, for small screen small label.

Answer (score 28):

In Bootstrap 3 they do not have separate classes for different styles of labels.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/

However, you can customize bootstrap classes that way. In your css file

```
.lb-sm {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.lb-md {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.lb-lg {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use header tags to change the sizes. For example, here is a medium sized label and a small-sized label

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3>Example heading <span class="label label-default">New</span></h3>
<h6>Example heading <span class="label label-default">New</span></h6>
```

They might add size classes for labels in future Bootstrap versions.

Comment: OK. But how could I use this classes dyanmically? Like in column size col-md-6 col-xs-12.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to do 2 things to make a Bootstrap label (or anything really) adjust sizes based on screen size:

- Use a media query per display size range to adjust the CSS.
- Override CSS sizing set by Bootstrap. You do this by making your CSS rules more specific than Bootstrap's. By default, Bootstrap sets `.label { font-size: 75% }`. So any extra selector on your CSS rule will make it more specific.

Here's an example CSS listing to accomplish what you are asking, using the default 4 sizes in Bootstrap:

```
@media (max-width: 767) {
    /* your custom css class on a parent will increase specificity */
    /* so this rule will override Bootstrap's font size setting */
    .autosized .label { font-size: 14px; }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .autosized .label { font-size: 16px; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .autosized .label { font-size: 18px; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .autosized .label { font-size: 20px; }
}
```

Here is how it could be used in the HTML:

```
<!-- any ancestor could be set to autosized -->
<div class="autosized">
    ...
        ...
            <span class="label label-primary">Label 1</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have

```
<span class="label label-default">New</span>
```

just add the style="font-size:XXpx;", ej.

```
<span class="label label-default" style="font-size:15px;">New</span>
```

Comment: This question is about expanding the label to the size of the screen, rather than increasing the size of the text in the label.